# How to set home page in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $this->layout = 'landing';
    $loginForm = new LoginForm();
    if (\Yii::$app->request->getIsPost()) {
        $loginForm->load(\Yii::$app->request->post());
        if ($loginForm->validate()) {
            $user = $loginForm->getUser();
            \Yii::$app->user->login($user);
            return $this->goHome();
        }
    }
}
```

method `goHome()` sends to the home page. I have added `'' => 'site/index'` to the URL Manager earlier to send people to the `SiteController` and Index action, but Yii2 does not do anything. How to set up a correct home page rule?

Comment: can you provide your url manager configuration? For basic-app it should be in config/web.php section components -> urlManager
A create read are the docs about [routing/url creation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#url-rules)

Comment: Set  'defaultRoute' => 'controller/action', in your config.

Answer (score 1):

You should write homeUrl parameter on config/main.php. For example:

```
return [
        'id' => 'app-frontend',
        'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
        'bootstrap' => ['log'],
        'homeUrl' => ['some/home-url-example'],
        'modules' => [
          ...
        ],
       ...
    ]
```